# Updating a paid domain or subdomain to a dynamic ip

Tags: domain, ip, subdomain

i was wondering if there was a service that is totaly free that can update the subdomain registered IP adress in the registry automaticly ?

Like if i had a update script on the server that checks in each day or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a workaround. I use a dydns or noip account linked to me router and on my dns hoster (like godaddy) I forward the traffic to that subdomain.

dyndns or noip offer a windows too in case your router does not suport it.

Comment: Sometimes we try to do complicated things when we have simple things that can do it. In my router dyndns is supported, just finished by setting it up and gona point the subdomain.

Thank you again.